# Dynamic component and template loading with VueJS

Tags: javascript, mvvm, vue.js

I'm considering using VueJS for a multi page website. In the official example of [routing](https://github.com/yyx990803/vue/blob/master/test/functional/fixtures/routing.html#L15), they show that you can dynamically change the template and component based on the URL, but they still have all the HTML templates and JS components in one file that's loaded all at once.

My website is going to be quite large, and I want to load everything only when required. So my question is: **How can I asynchronously load these HTML templates and JS components *on demand* when the URL is changed?** It would be helpful to just show how the above routing example could be modified for dynamic script loading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: see [Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components) section in the official docs.

Comment: Hello, Evan. Does vue.js get something like templateUrl now? I can only find things like using with webpack. This will restrict by deploy environment. eg. I have a site built with Angular on GitHub pages without pre-building, everything would be newest as I push the source code to GitHub. This is a typical sense that I cannot use webpack.

Comment: Because links (like this one) break it's useful to add the actual code in the answer where we know it will last.

Answer (score 3):

Hardcoded, but work.  Webpack solution is too hard for beginners, like me.

```
var router = new VueRouter({hashbang:false})
var routerMap = {};

router.beforeEach( function (transition) {
    var path = transition.to.path;
    if ((path != '/') && !(path in routerMap)) {
        _ajax('/reports/'+ path + '.html', function(res){//$.ajax replacement (async)
            routerMap[path] = {
                component: {
                    template: res 
                }
            }; 
            router.on(path, routerMap[path]);   //associate dynamically loaded component            

            transition.abort();     //abort current
            router.stop();                          
            router.start();         //restart router
            router.go(path);        //init new transition to the same path
        });//_ajax 
  } else 
        transition.next();          //default action for already loaded content
});
```